# How do I input two integers with a dash in between?

Tags: c, scanf

I am suppose to input book information and one of the information is the month and year the book is published.

The program is suppose to read it with the following format: `02-2012`

which shows that `02` is the month and `2012` is the year.

```
printf("Enter month and year book publish:\n");
scanf("%d[^-]%d",&book[i].month,&book[i].year);
```

I tried doing it this way but it does not work.

Comment: or you can write `scanf("%d%c%d",&book[i].month,&tempCh,&book[i].year);`

Comment: Note: Not testing the return value of scanf is a recipe for surprises.

Comment: The square bracket thingie is actually a conversion specifier, so it should be `%*[^-]`, the percent is required else it's a literal square bracket. The asterisk suppresses assignment since you don't want to keep the dash. And: you must check the return value!

Comment: What should your code do if the user types input in the wrong format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution:

```
char temp;
scanf("%d%c%d", &book[i].month,&temp,&book[i].year);
```

You can later validate the input checking if temp contains a dash.

Comment: If it works, mark this answer as a correct one by pressing this gray tick sign next to the answer. This will make the tick green and will show to the community that it has solved your problem.

Comment: This answer lacks showing validation which should include the return value of `scanf()` and `temp`.  See [@Jens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120874/how-do-i-input-two-integers-with-a-dash-in-between/38128133#comment63674217_38120874) comment.

Answer (score 5):

The trick is to cast the input into the format you want, and this can be done by forcing the input format via scanf.

```
scanf("%d-%d", &book[i].month, &book[i].year);
```

Dash between the two %d would swallow up '-' entered by user.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for this,

```
scanf("%d-%d,&book[i].month,&book[i].year);
```

This will ignore the `-` in the input.

Answer (score 0):

Use `"%n"` to detect complete parsing

```
printf("Enter month and year book publish:\n");
int n = 0;
scanf("%d-%d%n", &book[i].month, &book[i].year, &n);
if (n) Success();
```

Even better, use `fgets()` rather than `scanf()`

```
char buf[100];
fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
int n = 0;
sscanf(buf, "%d-%d %n", &book[i].month, &book[i].year, &n);
// Also detects that trailing junk after the 2nd number does not exist.
if (n && buf[n] == '\0') Success();
```